# View Expand Animation Affects Other Views by Using "animateLayoutChanges" in Nested Layout

Tags: java, android, android-animation, android-expandable-list-view

For the orange part, I use `android:animateLayoutChanges="true"` on its `LinearLayout` with `setVisibility(visible/gone)` to achieve the expand animation, but the last `TextView` (the whole row) looks affected by that animation (it flickrs), also the whole part below the orange part didn't move up/down smoothly (looks no animation at all). Any help I will be appreciated. Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Your question is not clear

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, finally I found the solution:

1. Add `android:animateLayoutChanges="true"` to your **will-be-resized** `ViewGroup`.
2. Use `setVisibility()` to control the visibility of your **target** `View`.
3. Add `android:animateLayoutChanges="true"` to the **outer** `ViewGroup` of your **will-be-resized** `ViewGroup`. This **outer** `ViewGroup` must be the one who contains all the **position-will-be-changed** `View`.
4. Add following code in your `Activity` before `setVisibility()`, the `rootLinearLayout` is the **outer** `ViewGroup` I mentioned above:

   ```
   LayoutTransition layoutTransition = rootLinearLayout.getLayoutTransition();
   layoutTransition.enableTransitionType(LayoutTransition.CHANGING);
   ```

---

**Reminder:**

1. If you miss the 3rd step, you will get a null pointer exception.
2. If you miss the 1st step, you will still get a good expand animation, but a bad collapse, you will see your **target** `View` will be disappeared suddenly first, then the `ViewGroup` collapses.

---

Result:

[image]

Comment: You can also use a rotation animation on a right arrow image to make it smooth too